# Probability - Aptitude

Tags: probability

A drawer holds 4 red hats and 4 blue hats.  What is the probability of getting exactly three red hats or exactly three blue hats when taking out 4 hats randomly out of the drawer and immediately returning every hat to the drawer before taking out the next?

A. 1/2

B. 1/8

C. 1/4

D. 3/8

We write all the possible outcomes or there is some trick to solve these types?

Comment: This particular situation is described well by a [Binomial Random Variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_random_variable)

Comment: $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. Multiply my favorable outcomes, i.e, $4\choose 1$ gives us $${4\choose 1}\times \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** There are $2^4$ equally likely outcomes. Finding the number of "favourable" outcomes is good.

There is also  a perhaps familiar formula ("binomial distribution")

This problem is exactly the same as: "We toss a fair coin $4$ times. What is the probability of exactly $3$ heads or exactly $3$ tails?"

Comment: havent got it yet :(

Comment: What is the probability of $3$ heads in $4$ tosses? It can happen in $4$ ways, THHH, HTHH, HHTH, HHHT. similarly, $3$ tails can happen in $4$ ways, total $8$. There are $2^4$ total possibilities. So probability is $\frac{8}{2^4}$.

Comment: oh ok, thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. I hope that everything is clear. In general, the probability of $k$ heads in $n$ tosses of a fair coin is $\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^n}$.